# How can I access AWS CLI resources from C#?

Tags: amazon-web-services

do you know if aws has any api to programmatically access its resources? for example:

```
https://api.aws.com/apigateway/myApi/getEndpoints
```

Or some way to use the CLI from .Net, for example:

```
var json = RunCli ("aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id 1234123412");
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The AWS SDK for .NET provides the AWS Resource APIs for .NET. These resource APIs provide a resource-level programming model that enables you to write code to work more directly with resources that are managed by AWS services.

Answer (score 0):

AWS resources can be accessed via AWS Management Console, SDK/API and CLI. Here is some examples:

1. [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)
2. [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)